# What is the difference between "He is polite" and "He is being polite"?

Tags: grammar, differences

Can any one please explain the usage and meaning of "He is polite" and "He is being polite".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> He is polite.

This is a simple statement describing a property of this person. You could also say:

> He is tall.
>   He is Chinese.

These are things that are generally true about this person at any given moment.

> He is being polite.

This describes an attribute of what this person is currently *doing*. "He" may generally be a very impolite person or not, but at this specific moment, he is being polite.

Actually, the sentence has also an implied meaning: he's being polite implies that he is saying something, or reacting to a situation, in a way that does not reflect his real intentions, but he is, for the sake of politeness, saying or doing something he doesn't fully agree with:

> He agreed that John's idea was a good one, but he proposed a completely different approach yesterday. I guess he's just being polite.

In this case, he probably disagrees with John's idea, but for the sake of politeness he tells John the idea has merit.

Answer (score 2):

> "He is polite"

means what it appears to mean, i.e. it is in his nature to be polite.

> "He is being polite"

means that he is making a particular effort to *appear* polite right now, despite the fact that the situation is one in which a lack of politeness would be understandable — for instance, because somebody has just insulted him, or has said something totally stupid, or is behaving badly in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

“He is polite” means the person *always*, or at least *generally*, applies good manners, etiquette, and other informal social rules.

“He is being polite” means the person is applying good manners or etiquette *on this specific occasion*.

The latter sentence may also imply that he has expressed a falsehood as some kind of white lie. Example: “When he told you that you are an excellent singer, he was merely being polite.”